# Access Dropdown to filter subform

Tags: ms-access, subform

Apologies if this has been answered but being new to access i cant see what will help me,

I have a access form that as a subform in it that displays an engineer name and a tickbox to select when logging downtime for the engineering team. however there is 4 teams and they are generally getting bigger which now means we have to scroll through the names to get to an engineer we want.

I have a list of all the engineers and what team they are associated to on 1 table and on the main form there is a dropdown with the teams on. When i select a team from the dropdown i want the subform to filter out any engineers that dont belong to select team.

**Additional Information**

Subform_SelectEngineer

Dropdown name is TeamFilter

Hope this is substantial information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on after update for your Teamfilter, set your

```
  subform_selectengineer.filter = "[TeamName] = '" & me.teamfilter & "'"
  subform_selectenginner.filteron = true
```

Comment: apologies can you go into a bit more detail as to where i need this code as i said previous im new to access and the database was created by someone who as now left. The dropdown is on the main form along with some input values

Comment: Select your drop down, go to the event tab, and choose 'After Update' Choose code, not macro and paste that code block. make sure the names are right

Comment: hmmm okay i done that but it does not update, The combobox name is TeamFilter, should i have subform_selectengineer or should it be the name of the subform which is child26

Comment: It should be the name of your subform -- child26