# Filtering a subform (Datasheet) using listbox

Tags: ms-access, vba

My access form has a datasheet subform, when I use Apply.Filter macro action I cannot change combo-boxes in subform - It keeps refreshing or something like this.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15099392/access-dropdown-to-filter-subform.  A quick search for "[ms-access] filter subform" also returns other various results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access Dropdown to filter subform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15099392/access-dropdown-to-filter-subform)